# Is there any circuit like "Burglar alarm " or "Proximity dector" with a range of 100 meters

Tags: rf, infrared, transmitter, receiver

I am in search of a circuit which works with 
IR or RF wave with a range of 100 meter to detect proximity or burglar.

I need this to detect the presence of human or animals 
One thing important is i can only use the circuit in this way.

0metere ------------------------------------------------------- 100 Meter

Signaler (IR)  ...................................................................>|(obstacle)

Receiver (IR or RF) <---------------<---------------------<<<<|(reflected from obstracle)

That is I cant place the receiver at the end of 100th meter, but it much work with
reflection...

> I have found the same circuit but it has a small range of less than a
>   **0.5 meter**
>
> The [circuit I have found is  "Circuit download...."](http://www.efymagonline.com/pdf/circuit-4.pdf)

Comment: 100m is a very long way for an IR reflective detector type of circuit, they are normally used at much closer ranges. Have a look at PIR sensors and Fresnel lenses (or a different narrow range lens if the detection area is small), some of the external security light type circuits have a pretty long range.

Comment: Would a 'pencil' beam like a laser be OK? It might be worth updating the question to say at the end of the 100 meters how broad the detection area should be, and if it needs to be exactly 100 meters range or if say 100-200 would be OK.

Comment: @PeterJ , is it possible to but pencil beam laser from market ? , i need anu thing which must be invisible and also the range is 0 to 100meter that is within the range

Comment: @OliGlaser : can you explain  me a little bit clear , is it possible with IR or RF or need to go with anything , this is for outdoor purpose the medium must be  invisible

Comment: @cc4re - Yes, this is totally invsible as it does not output anything - PIR stands for *Passive* Infra Red sensor, it works by detecting the IR emitted from hot objects (e.g. body heat) compared to the surroundings. Have a read of the [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_infrared_sensor) and see if you think it's suitable for your project.

Comment: @cc4re You can buy infrared lasers that are invisible, but aligning one and making sure it's safe and detecting the output will be far from trivial. Oli's suggestion is simpler if it works for you.

Comment: @OliGlaser Thanks buddy i was reading that , it looks good , is there any sample circuit available to build

Comment: @PeterJ Thanks but i am in search of a circuit , i think  somebody can help me .

Comment: @cc4re - I'll add an answer with a couple of circuits, give me a few minutes

Comment: @starblue : in front of my outhouse  there is a 100m wide road , i want to know if there is some one going across it at midnight , here i cant put the sensor or transmitter on both sides of the road, what i can do is to put in front of my outhouse

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few PIR circuits, ranging from very simple to quite complex. The better ones use a window comparator setup and adjust for ambient light conditions.

Here is a page full of [PIR circuits](http://educypedia.karadimov.info/electronics/sensorsinfrared.htm), and another [good page](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/sensors/pir.html) from LadyAda. An [app note](http://educypedia.karadimov.info/library/pirmanual.PDF) detailing some common circuits.

Here is one pretty typical circuit (from [this page](http://www.glolab.com/pirparts/infrared.html)):

[image: Example 1]

Here is about the simplest circuit:

[image: Example 2]

And one that appears to have ambient light compensation (notice phototransistor at bottom left)

[image: Example 3]

Have a read through the tutorials/links and then have a browse around for circuits, there are literally hundreds of examples out there, some better (and better explained) than others. Choose your lens carefully - if you don't want a typical wide angle security type detector, then I think this will be crucial to getting good results. Experiment with a few options to see what works best.
The PIR sensors (component only) are available from places like Farnell, Mouser, LadyAda, etc. Or you can purchase ready made modules from various places.

Answer (score 1):

We have had pretty good results using the Zilog ZMOTION chip to build a PIR sensor for shorter distances around 20-30 feet with an appropriate Fresnel lense. To get any where close to your 100m detection range would definitely require a custom designed Fresnel lense. BTW We also worked with both Ultrasonic and simple X-Band microwave designs neither of which were capable of reaching 100m range.

There is some good information on the Zilog site:
http://www.zilog.com/index.php?option=com_product&task=product&businessLine=147&id=148&parent_id=148&Itemid=77